# Slow motion tween text isn't smooth

Tags: flash, text, performance, smoothing, motion

i have to create a movie where a text string move in horizontal.

the problem is that in the movie (800px wide) the text should go from right to left in about 7 seconds (so it have to go about 400px to the left in 7 sec).

i created a motion-tween with ease for my "text" and the tween is long (at 30fps) 30*7=210 frames.

the result is that the text DON'T MOVE FLUID... it's not a uniform movement... it's too visible the fact that it moves X pixel each x frames. it's the exact opposite of SMOOTH MOVEMENT.

How can i obtain a smooth slow-motion text movement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer my self working on another project.

Solution -> ong each TEXT you have in the flash file click d EMBED FONT button and import UpperCase Lowercase Numbers and COmmonSymbols.

NOW TEXT-TWEEN GO VERY SMOOTH

Optional: USE A TWEEN FRAMEWORK (for AS2 or AS3) !

Answer (score 2):

In the text properties select "Antialias for animation"